# Sigma graph not displaying, but no error message

Tags: sigma.js

I'm trying to make a POC using
http://sigmajs.org/
on gexf data generated by
https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki-grapher/.

The attempt is here, not displaying anything:
http://galerie.microalg.info/profgra.html

Anyone please?

Comment: I have made a plunker here http://embed.plnkr.co/1OjZtRcHxa78pWjlhgQi/preview, and try to display your graph but with no result ... sorry

Answer (score 2):

That's because the nodes don't have a size or a position.
You can loop on the nodes and give them what they need like so:

```
sigma.parsers.gexf(
  'profgra.gexf',
  { container: 'graph-container' },
  // This will be executed after graph loading:
  function(sigmaInstance) {
    sigmaInstance.graph.nodes().forEach(function(node, i, a) {
      // On a circle:
      node.x = Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length);
      node.y = Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length);
      // Default size:
      node.size = 1;
    });
    sigmaInstance.refresh();
  }
);
```